# App name not centered on Homescreen?

Tags: ios, icons

I just noticed a weird bug where my app's name is not centered under it's icon. I've tried googling but can't find where this bug might have come from. I've checked my build settings and there are no spaces in my app name that would cause it to be off-center on the home screen. Would anyone know what causes this?

Comment: Check for spaces in the name in iTunes Connect